# Audio playing slower than its actual audio duration in AudioWorkletProcessor

Tags: javascript, audio, web-audio-api, webapi

I have a webpage that collects audio from microphone and store it for 3s, and then pass to a custom AudioWorkletProcessor that plays it. When the audio is played, it should get deleted from memory. Ideally the audio stored would corresponds to 3s, as we are playing audio from 3s ago, and the time shall sync. However, I see that the stored audio is growing, indicating that my AudioWorkletProcessor is playing slower than the actual audio duration.

In play_audio_processor.js

```
class PlayAudioProcessor extends AudioWorkletProcessor {
    audioData = [];
    index = 0;
    silenceFrameCount = 0;

    constructor() {
        super();
        // Microphone audio data, data is float32 array.
        this.port.onmessage = (data) => {
            console.log("Data amount: ", this.audioData.length); // This is growing
            console.log("Silence frame count: ", this.silenceFrameCount); // This is constant
            // console.log(data);
            if (data.data.length > 0) {
                this.audioData.push(data.data);
            }
        };
    }

    process(inputs, outputs, parameters) {
        const output = outputs[0];
        const outputChannel1 = output[0];
        for (let i = 0; i < outputChannel1.length; ++i) {
            if (this.audioData.length > 0) {
                outputChannel1[i] = this.audioData[0][this.index];
                this.index++;
                if (this.index == this.audioData[0].length) {
                    this.audioData.shift();
                    this.index = 0;
                }
            } else {
                outputChannel1[i] = 0;
                this.silenceFrameCount++;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }
}

registerProcessor("play-audio-processor", PlayAudioProcessor);
```

I wonder if it's my process function is taking too long to execute, and it adds up the latency.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's because the `sampleRate` of the `AudioContext` is different as the one from the microphone. It also looks like the code doesn't compensate for audio data that arrives too late. Each time you increase `silenceFrameCount` you would also need to discard 128 samples of the audio data to not increase the latency.

But if all you want to do is to delay the audio by 3 seconds you could also pipe the `MediaStream` from the microphone into your `AudioContext` using a `MediaStreamAudioSourceNode` and then apply a `DelayNode` with a `delayTime` of 3 seconds.

```js
// Let's imagine there is an audioContext and a mediaStream.
const mediaStreamAudioDestinationNode = new MediaStreamAudioDestinationNode(audioContext, { mediaStream });
const delayNode = new DelayNode(audioContext, { delayTime: 3 });

mediaStreamAudioDestinationNode
    .connect(delayNode)
    .connect(audioContext.destination);
```

Comment: The audio passed in is at 16kHz, and the sampleRate of AudioContext is also set to 16kHz. The audio sounds normal to me, no strange pitch. I needed this because I'm actually mutating the audio in my server and sent it back, so I cannot simply use DelayNode.

Comment: What about the other potential issue? Does it help if you drop samples each time you have to increase `silenceFrameCount`?